# how to Type farsi text in 3dMax, directly in viewport?

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca4V8.jpg)
is there another way for make 3d text directly in 3ds max in persian language (farsi) ?
i already tried autodesk MAXScript Reference, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You must use the version of the 2013 and onwards.

In the 2013 version:

1)Select 2d shapes and select text button.

2)Write your text in the text box.